# Print single quotes in shell script using option -c

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, echo

This may sound novice but I tried everything to get this to work.
I want to print a word with single quotes : **'John'** in shell script. I cant replace `/bin/bash -l -c` as this part of code is run by Java and I have to pass the shell command as a string. I tried with `echo -e` option as well.

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'echo "'John'"'
```

The output I want is:

```
'John'
```

I tried escaping the single quotes but nothing helped so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can't nest single quotes in bash, so the line is interpreted as

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'echo "'John'"'
                |......| ---------- single quoted
                       |....| ----- not quoted
                            |.| --- quoted
```

So, properly escape the single quotes:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo "'\''John'\''"'
```

or, if the string in single quotes is really simple,

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo "'\'John\''"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the double quotes and escaping the single quotes:

```
/bin/bash -l -c "echo \'John\'"
```

Answer (score 0):

A common workaround is to use `printf` so you don't need to use literal single quotes in the format string.

```
bash -l -c 'printf "\x27John\x27\n"'
```

(Using `bash -l` here is probably misdirected and nonportable.)